# c wire question

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac

I have a gas fired hot water boiler with 18/2 thermostat wire running up to my regular non wifi thermostat . I want to know if I ran a single (blue ) 18 g wire from my c terminal on my new wifi thermostat down to my 24 volt 40 va transformer and connected to my c terminal on that transformer on top of the c wire going to my existing zone valve and boiler control wiring  (both wires on the same c screw) will that supply the c wire requirement so the wifi thermostat would work ?  Unlike a furnace there is no other ( c terminal ) on the hot water boiler .

Comment: What make and model is your boiler? Is there a reason you can't replace the existing thermostat cable?

Comment: I can't rule that out as a possibility.  Instead of telling us what you don't have please tell us what you do have.